# Rails application migration from Rails-1.1.2 to 2.0.0 and greator

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Trying to migrate application from `Rails-1.1.2` to `2.0.0` to current version.

Basic problem is can't find documentation for it.

I think in Rails 1.1.2 they don't have command to update the application like `bundle update rails` or `rails app:update`.

Directly changing ruby version gives boot error.

Comment: When working on a legacy application that's *this old*, it's seriously worth considering a rewrite rather than an upgrade. I know that this doesn't answer the question, and I suspect you're considering it already, but I feel this is worth emphasising in case others are in a similar position and see your question.

Comment: Rails 1.2 was released on **January 19, 2007**. That means your application has lacked a significant upgrade in **over 12 years**.

Comment: Yes its too old to migrate, but project only have crud operations in it, so i think its movable. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If it's not a giant app I think your best bet would be to just create a new project (5.2 or the in beta 6.0) and copy in the relevant code.

Comment: Thanks sure can try this approach.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to do is to upgrade your Rails app to version `1.2.6`, which is documented [here](https://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2007/1/19/rails-1-2-rest-admiration-http-lovefest-and-utf-8-celebrations/).

After that you can upgrade to Rails `2.0`, which is documented [here](https://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2007/12/7/rails-2-0-it-s-done/).

The Rails [releases page](https://weblog.rubyonrails.org/releases/) might be a useful page for you to check out, since they hold the info on how to upgrade. Like you said, there's hardly any information on how to upgrade the older Rails versions, so the official releases page is your best bet.

I'd upgrade to each release individually, so from `1.1.2` to `1.2.0`, then to `1.2.6`. Then go to `2.0`, `2.1`, etc. Update your Ruby seperate from it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly migrate rails-1.1.x to rails-2.0 due to till Rails 2.3 doesn't have built-in bundler support because it came out before Bundler and no Gemfile in rails also that not a good way to directly update the ruby.

Note: before migrate to any version make sure you have more than 70% test coverage.

**Steps help to migrate**

- Change the rails version (rails 1.1.x to rails 2.0) manually (means in vendor folder).
- Run the test case and fix the failing syntax in your code (If any)
- Then migrate rails 2.0 to rails 2.higher version (make sure higher than rails 2.3)
- Again Run the test case and fix the failing syntax in your code (If any)
- Then migrate rails 2.x to rails 3 pre version
- Now you can add Gemfile put all gems into that upgrade your bundler gem.
- Now you can migrate the ruby version as well.
- Again Run the test case and fix the failing syntax in your code (If any)
- Then migrate rails 3.0-pre to rails 3.higher version
- Again Run the test case and fix the failing syntax in your code (If any)
- Then migrate rails 3.x to rails 4 pre version
- Now you can migrate the ruby version as well.

This is very long successful process for rails migration if your rails version older that 3.0.

There is one more way to achieve that. If you just want a Gemfile, rather than Bundler integration with Rails, you can create one easily enough.

```
gem install bundler
bundle init
```

Then follow below Guide to The Rails Command Line may help you, especially the section that covers `rake gems:install`.

`https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/command_line.html#rake-is-ruby-make`

I hope that help you.

Answer (score 0):

Before looking at starting to upgrade an app from such an old version of Rails, I'd suggest reviewing how complicated it is and questioning if it would actually be quicker to build from scratch in the most recent version rather than go through so many upgrades.